# Elastic IP routing to non-AWS IP (IPv4)

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a customer that needs to have a second IP address on a server.  If we obtain a AWS/Azure ip address can we redirect that IP to the server?  Their current hosting provider (Linode) will only allow 2nd ip addresses on a case by case bases.   This is needed on 12+ servers.  This is for a DNS/UDP service, so domain redirects would not work.  Route53 looks like it might support this but I am not sure.

Bottom line is that we need a IPv4 "cloud" ip address that would support redirecting to another static ip address.  All traffic is UDP.  It doesn't have to be AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An redirect would look like this:

```
client
       ->
          EC2
       <-
client
       ->
          Linode
       <-
client
```

But IP addresses cannot be "redirected". It is not possible to have a server respond to a client with "go here instead". That's not how TCP/IP works, especially UDP.

The best you could do is setup a server on something like EC2, assign it an Elastic IP address, then have software installed on that EC2 that would forward the connection on to your desired recipient.

To the client, it's just talking to your EC2 instance. Behind the scenes, your EC2 instance is forwarding packets on to Linode.

Doing this, the connection would go as follows:

```
client
       -> 
          EC2
              -> 
                 Linode
              <-
          EC2
      <-
client
```

Nginx or other firewall/NAT software may be able to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use CloudFront as a forward proxy server. Get the Cloudfront CDN after creation and associate it with a CNAME in your domain.

Comment: This is for a DNS/UDP service.  A UDP ip address.  CloudFront as far as I know doesn't speak ip addresses, only domains